# Mask for image padding in semantic segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, data-augmentation

I'm using data augmentation for a semantic segmentation task, where some images are cropped or rotated. As a result, some padding is added to ensure that the image is always the same size. These operations are also performed on the mask. My question is, should the mask for the padded region be different from that of the background class?

Consider the example in the following image from [this medium post](https://medium.com/@thimblot/data-augmentation-boost-your-image-dataset-with-few-lines-of-python-155c2dc1baec):
[image]

The masks are not shown, but assume we only have two classes: 0: background and 1: cat. My question is, should I introduce a third class for the padding of the transformed images, i.e., the black region in the corners of the images in the second line? By default, the function I'm using marks these regions as background. Should I assign a different semantic label to the padding manually? If not, are there any situations where this would be desirable?

The only example I can think of is if there are different types of backgrounds that must be identified (e.g., a class for forest background, another class for snowy background, etc.). What is the current best practice for semantic segmentation?

Comment: Have you manege to get some answer ? I am having similar issue. I Have images generated by GAN network, I need to paste them in to black image with correct dimensions and extract annotations. I am wondering how black or white padding will impact the training. According to this paper [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiQ-OjJoc7xAhVRx4sKHakAAzcQFjAMegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F2101.12322&usg=AOvVaw3gnos_tL3yPRHKfGaLa6wO) it should not matter much.

Comment: I have not. I used the same label as the background and in my case, it seemed to work ok. I'll take a look at the paper you linked.